# Magento 2: How to defaultly open "content 2" tab?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am using  **accordion** for tab open and close.
How to open default "**content 2**" tab?

```
<div class="block filter" id="layered-filter-block" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": true, "collateral": { "openedState": "filter-active", "element": "body" } }}'>                              
    <div class="block-content filter-content">                  
        <div class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list" data-role="content" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": true, "multipleCollapsible": true}}'>
            <div data-role="collapsible" class="filter-options-item" >
                <div data-role="title" class="filter-options-title">title 1</div>
                <div data-role="content" class="filter-options-content">content 1</div>
            </div>  
            <div data-role="collapsible" class="filter-options-item" >
                <div data-role="title" class="filter-options-title">title 2</div>
                <div data-role="content" class="filter-options-content">content 2</div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="collapsible" class="filter-options-item" >
                <div data-role="title" class="filter-options-title">title 3</div>
                <div data-role="content" class="filter-options-content">content 3</div>
            </div>                  
        </div>                      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On page Load **Dynamically require to open some particulate tab** please use below code instade of

```
data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": [1,4], "multipleCollapsible": true}}'
```

**Solution**

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'accordion'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {                      
        jQuery( "#narrow-by-list" ).accordion({
            "openedState": "active",
            "collapsible": true,
            "active": [1,4], /** Integrat Dynamic open tab  */
            "multipleCollapsible": true,
        });
    });                 
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have used .ready instead of the domReady! functionality?

Comment: @BenCrook yes, After after page load i want to use this functionality on my acript.

Comment: It's best practice to use the domReady! functionality so your dependencies are aware of the document ready requirement. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332628/requirejs-domready-plugin-vs-jquery-document-ready for more info

Comment: How to open Apply Discount code tab in cart page?

Comment: Can any help me with how to close all active tabs on outside side click? @BenCrook

Answer (score 15):

[Magento 2 docs - Accordion](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html#collaps_active)

Set `active` to the tab you'd like to be open by default instead of true. For example:

```
$("#element").accordion({ active: "0 1"});
$("#element").accordion({ active: [0,1]});
```

So in your case it should be:

```
data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": "2", "multipleCollapsible": true}}'
```

Replacing 2 with the tab you require to be open.

### TLDR

Change `"active": true`, to `"active": 1` where 1 is the tab you wish to be open by default.

Comment: Thank for giving solution.
But All tabs are cumming Dynamically and how to set particular tab open by some condition.
for eg. 
dynamically I require 2nd and 4th tab can be opened.

Comment: I'm not too sure if the built in Accordion has a way to do this, as a quick example I've done it with jQuery (using Require JS to load jQuery), this will open even tabs when a button is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function($) {
        $('.test').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.filter-options-item:nth-child(even) .filter-options-content').toggle();

            console.log('test');

        });
    });
</script>
```

I can't seem to format the above into code.  What is your use case?

Comment: If you mean having the 2nd and 4th tab open by default you can change `active": "3"` to `active": [1,3]` which will open the 2nd and 4th. But I'm not sure how to do that dynamically.

Comment: What if you want all tabs to be open by default?

Comment: @10basetom I'm not sure off the top of my head, I presume setting `active:` to either `true` or an array of your tabs to be opened such as `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: @BenCrook I tried `true` but that didn't work. Passing an array worked, but if you don't know the number of filters ahead of time it's a bit unpractical :(.

Comment: I need to open Apply discount code tab by default on cart page