# Display sidebar

Tags: magento-2.1, sidebar, theme-overriding

[image]

I'm using **Magento 2** and I'm displayed many attributes such as color, price, etc. on the sidebar, on all the category's pages but I want to display all categories, brands and color same as the price.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please make it clear that in which manner you are saying that you want to show it same as the price? Means in design sense or in functionality sense or in selection element sense?

Comment: I want all tabs to be open by default

Answer (score 0):

If you want How to defaultly open then follow the below link:-

[Magento 2: How to defaultly open "content 2" tab?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102725/magento-2-how-to-defaultly-open-content-2-tab)

Comment: can you explain me in detail?