# Magento 2.4.3 - Edit Products - Tab Configuration is always expanded / open / shown

Tags: product, tabs, edit, magento2.4.3.p1

this is a minor issue that annoys me a little bit.

I have Magento 2.4.3 installed.

In the Edit Product Dialog (backend) the tab "Configuration" is always shown / expanded, while all other tabs are hidden / closed.

[image]

Why is that and how can I also close the Configuration tab?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102725/magento-2-how-to-defaultly-open-content-2-tab

You can refer above link

Comment: I thought there might be an option in the backend of Magento. I do not even know how to make something like that by myself. More important would be the informtion if that is the case with other M2 installations two or a bug in mine.

Comment: No there is not an option in backend, also it is not a bug a normal think in all Magento instance.